Flutter sdk error '(exit code: 1 last line of pub output: "Because Room_Booking requires SDK version >=3.4.0 <4.0.0, version solving failed." )
PS D:\projects\coding\web dev\room booking\my_app> flutter clean
PS D:\projects\coding\web dev\room booking\my_app> flutter pub upgrade
Resolving dependencies...
The current Dart SDK version is 2.19.0-146.2.beta.
Because Room_Booking requires SDK version >=3.4.0 <4.0.0, version solving failed.
pub finished with exit code 1
PS D:\projects\coding\web dev\room booking\my_app> flutter pub get
The current Dart SDK version is 2.19.0-146.2.beta.
Because Room_Booking requires SDK version >=3.4.0 <4.0.0, version solving failed.
Running "flutter pub get" in my_app...
pub get failed
command: "D:\programes\flutter\bin\cache\dart-sdk\bin\dart __deprecated_pub --verbosity=warning get
--no-precompile"
pub env: {
"FLUTTER_ROOT": "D:\programes\flutter",
"PUB_ENVIRONMENT": "flutter_cli:get",
"PUB_CACHE": "C:\Users\Administrateur\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache",
}
exit code: 1
last line of pub output: "Because Room_Booking requires SDK version >=3.4.0 <4.0.0, version solving failed."
IDK whats the problem in this project

It's in your error message. Just upgrade your flutter sdk from stable secure channel. The sdk version must be greater then 3.4.0. Or you can lower sdk version for your app on pubspec.yaml:
SDK version >=2.19.0 <4.0.0,

